# Python syntax error_ maybe indentation issue

Tags: python, indentation

Hi~  I have this syntax error in Python:

```
while true:
    print("Please type your name.")
    name = input()
    if name == "your name":
        break
print("Thanks!")
```

But looks like the code "print(Thanks!)" has syntax error~  I don't know why~ Thanks!

Comment: `true` should be `True`. Other than that, I don't know what problem you are seeing.

Comment: `NameError: name 'true' is not defined` Other than that, this code works fine.

Comment: It should be `while True`

Comment: Which Python version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7

Answer (score -1):

**Use the code below for Python 2.7**
And never ask your syntax problems.

```
while True:
    print("Please type your name.")
    name = raw_input()
    if name == "your name":
        break
print("Thanks!")
```